# Vagrant on Virtualbox provider multiple Network Adapters

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm building a vagrant Ubuntu/Xenial box (virtualbox provider) from windows host and I need to config 2 networks with using 2 different network adapters I already tried to with option:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.0.2.77", :mac =>  
"xxxxxxxxxxxx", bridge: "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM"
```

or modify virtualbox with the command:

```
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nic[N]", "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM"]
```

but I always get 2 networks using the same network adapter

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to solve this issue using command

```
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nic2", "bridged","--bridgeadapter2", "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM", "--cableconnected2", "off"]
```